# How to express acceleration in natural coordinates system?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

I know that what I am asking is easy but I can't understand how to deal and relate.

My question is this that we write that total acceleration of fluid particle as:
$$\vec{a}=\frac{\partial \vec{V}}{\partial t}+\big(\vec{V}\bullet \vec{\nabla}\big)\vec{V}$$
But in natural coordinates system we can also write that total acceleration of fluid particle as:
$$\vec{a}=\frac{\partial \vec{V}}{\partial t}+\vec{V}\frac{\partial \vec{V}}{\partial s}$$ where "s" is arclength parameter.
My question is How $$\frac{\partial \vec{V}}{\partial t}+|\vec{V}|\frac{\partial \vec{V}}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial \vec{V}}{\partial t}+\big(\vec{V}\bullet \vec{\nabla}\big)\vec{V}$$
Can anyone explain in detail.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First, a quibble: Your final LHS should read

$\displaystyle
\frac{\partial \vec{V}}{\partial t}+|\vec{V}|\frac{\partial \vec{V}}{\partial s}$

And that might be the clue you need to your answer, in fact.  $|\vec{V}|\frac{\partial}{\partial s}$ will equal $(\vec{V}\cdot\nabla)$ if and only if the "natural coordinate" is measuring length along the curve of the fluid element's path.  Another way to say it is that $\vec{V}$ must be tangent to the curve whose length $s$ measures.

To see this, imagine that $\vec{V}$ does indeed flow along the curved measured by $s$.  That means that if I draw tangent vectors all along that curve, they all point in the direction of local $\vec{V}$.  This means that $\vec{V}$ dotted with the gradient operator is the same as $|\vec{V}|$ multiplied by the change in length along the curve.

Looked at in another way,

$\displaystyle
\vec{V}\cdot\nabla = |\vec{V}|\hat{v}\cdot\nabla$

where $\hat{v}$ is the unit vector of $\vec{V}$.  Now, for any unit vector $\hat{u}$, the dot product $\hat{u}\cdot\nabla$ give the change per unit length along the direction of $\hat{u}$.  So the dot product $\hat{v}\cdot\nabla$ gives us the change per unit length *along the velocity*.  We know this change per unit length must be $\partial/\partial s$.  And so

$\displaystyle
\hat{v}\cdot\nabla = \frac{\partial}{\partial s}$

Therefore

$\displaystyle
\vec{V}\cdot\nabla = |\vec{V}|\hat{v}\cdot\nabla = |\vec{V}|\frac{\partial}{\partial s}$

Comment: sacamento Can yoy explain further sir please

Comment: sacamento Sir how $|\vec{V}|\frac{\partial}{\partial s}=\vec{V}\bullet\vec{\nabla}$

Comment: Added a new paragraph.  Hope it helps.

Comment: sacamento Sir I know that in case in case of natural coordinates system only one component of velocity will appear but how can we prove mathematically that $|\vec{V}|\frac{\partial}{\partial s}=\vec{V}\bullet\vec{\nabla}$

Comment: I've tried again.  See new paragraph.

Comment: sacamento  Sir I know that arclength of the streamline curve is: $s(t)=\int_{t_{0}}^{t} |\vec{V}| dt$ and from here we get that $\frac{ds}{dt}=|\vec{V}|$, can you try to prove the desired result from here, i.e, $\vec{V}\bullet \vec{{\nable}}=|\vec{V}|\frac{\partial}{\partial s}.$

Comment: Added a few more words of explanation.  Hope it helps.